# How to apply migrations to EF 7 context on instantiation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, initializer, entity-framework-core

I know I can do :

```
Database.Migrate();
```

after the context is ready. But I cannot get EF to do it when initialising my context, like you could do previously with EF 6.1 using `Database.SetInitializer` and `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`in the context constructor.

So, how can I ensure that the DB is created or updated **and** migrated using the available migrations before I make my first call to get data?

Answer (score 1):

Just instantiate the DbContext during app startup, and call Database.Migrate()